# how to make a scatter plot on jupyter notebook python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, scatter-plot

[I need to make a scatter plot and I am not sure how to do this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7VwG.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [5,7,8,7,2,17,2,9,4,11,12,9,6]
y = [99,86,87,88,111,86,103,87,94,78,77,85,86]

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

try that, as seen in:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ml_scatterplot.asp

Comment: And if you want some 3D options, go [here](https://github.com/fomightez/3Dscatter_plot-binder) press `launch binder` and work through the available notebooks. The plotly ones on the second page let you click and drag to rotate the view of the data.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of ax.plot use ax.scatter. You can, however, do it in a cleaner way as well, since you're using pandas with your data (I believe) you can do

```
data.plot(x=name_of_column1, y=name_of_column2, marker="o", ls="")
```